# handling about 450.000 files in a zip

Tags: java, performance, file-io, zip, out-of-memory

My question is simple. Would Java handle a .zip file with about 450,000 files in there? The code that I wrote would not load all of the files, just one specific file would be searched in the zip, and be read line by line. The file size is about 500kb.

Would this work or will I get an OutOfMemory Exception?

Oh sry, uncompressed there about 0,5MB. Zipped are they whole files about 250mb.

Ok, the name of the Files are IDs + Date(unique) in that zip file. If i have to check a log, ill call Java and give the ID + Date and Java is reading just that one file, never more.

Edit: It works, it works very well. About 400.000 files in a zip, if u have the Memory to Zip the Files works without any problem.

Edit2: It works on Linux Filesystems witout a problem, on NTFS sometimes it crashed. NTFS has a problem with that musch files in 1 Zip.

Comment: Try it, and them tell us.

Comment: Not helpful... I have edited the question @duffymo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the zip filesystem in Java 7, you can actually access one individual file pretty easily *and* open a `BufferedReader` on it.

First you have to create the `FileSystem`:

```
public static FileSystem getZipFileSystem(final String zipPath)
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(zipPath).toAbsolutePath();
    final Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<>();
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + path.toString());
    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env, null);
}
```

Once you have done that, you can create a `BufferedReader` from an entry in the zip itself:

```
try (
    final FileSystem fs = getZipFileSystem("/path/to/the.zip");
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(fs.getPath("path/to/entry"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    // operate on the reader
}
```

You could also read all lines in the entry at once using `Files.readAllLines()`.

If you wish to copy a zip entry to a file on the filesystem, you can also do that:

```
Files.copy(zipfs.getPath("path/to/entry"), Paths.get("file/on/local/fs"));
```

Or you can directly copy the result to an `OutputStream`, or directly create an entry from an `OutputStream`...

Or even walk the entire zip using `Files.walkFileTree()`.

Or get all the entries in a "directory" in a zip using `Files.newDirectoryStream()`. Note that as its name says, this is a *stream*; unlike `File.listFiles()` (which only works on files on disk anyway), this returns a iterator over the entries.

Or... Or... Or...

Note that a `FileSystem` needs to be `.close()`d.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to do.

If it's 0.5 MB/file and 450,000 files, you'll need 225GB.  You won't have enough memory to do all this in a single zip in memory even if you get 90% compression.

I'd recommend breaking it into manageable chunks.  You'll be able to parallelize that way too, so it's not a bad idea.